# Matlab: How to convert image coordinate to array indices

Tags: image, matlab, coordinate

I have a GUI which display 2D image. However, I am not able to recover data accurately by using mouse coordinates. This is because I am not able to convert image coordinates to array indices properly.

I use ginput to get mouse coordinates.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards
Dushyant

Comment: can you be a bit more explicit as to what you have tried? how do you get mouse coordinates? usig callbacks? using `ginput`?

Comment: Read this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html

Answer (score 0):

When displaying an image in matlab, your origin(for image) sits at top left corner of the image, x-axis increase towards downwards and y-axis increase towards right, while with mouse you get co-ordinates with x-axis increasing towards right and y-axis towards up(so a rotation of +90 degrees with respect to image co-ordinates plus a translation),,, so you have to transform  one of your co-ordinates to the other to get the right values, for example if your origin of figure window is at top left corner and image spans the whole frame then,,,

x_image = -y_mouse    and
y_image = x_mouse.

Comment: *x-axis increase towards downwards and y-axis increase towards right* Are you sure ?  That would make Matlab the only system in the universe which doesn't use *x-axis* to mean the one parallel to the horizon and  *y-axis* to mean the one parallel to the vertical.

Comment: in case of images,, yeah i'm sure,,,you can apply a scaling along x_axis on an image and see the image being scaled vertically,,

Comment: You seem to know better than the Mathworks: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html

Comment: what I meant was that if you access [2,3] pixel,, it would be 2 pixels downward and 3 towards right,,, and we usually consider [2,3] to be the position 2i+3j(in vector form),,, so 1st co-ordinate(x) increase downwards and 2nd(y) towards right,,, which is consistent with Mathworks,

Comment: @Salman Azmat   Thanks for your answer. However, I believe that I am understanding something wrong. Since all indices (x_mouse, y_mouse) and (x_image, y_image) has to be positive, I think that something is missing when you write: x_image = -y_mouse and
y_image = x_mouse.

Comment: yeah, that's because I assumed your origin of the figure to be on top left corner which probably is not the case here,,assume your origin is 'xo' pixels distant from the left boundary and 'yo' pixels downward from the upper boundary of figure, then you have to simply apply a translation which gives 
                             x_image = -(y_mouse-yo) = (-y_mouse+yo)
y_image = (x_mouse+xo)
now your x_image and y_image can not be negative,, but still y_mouse and x_mouse can be negative  and that depends on where you choose your origin while declaring the properties of figure object,,

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
fig=figure, imshow(myfigure);
[x, y] = getpts(fig);
```